# Unable to increment and print inside a Windows Batch for loop

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, auto-increment

I'm new to Windows batch.

I'm trying to read lines from a file `input.txt` and print `run<increment-value>` thus for the first line it should print `run1` and for the second line `run2` and so on.

Below is what I tried:

```
set /a c=1
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (index.txt) do (
set /a c=c+1
echo incvalue=run%c%
echo line=%%a
)
pause
```

In the output, I see the `line=` prints each line which is what I want but the incremental value of the loop always prints run1 i.e does not increment.

Can you please suggest?

Comment: Two things, **1.** You're not incrementing the value of the variable named `c` within your loop, you defined it with a value of `1` before the loop, and made no changes to that in your script. **2.** In order to increment it in the loop you'll want to delay variable expansion.

Comment: Sorry @Compo i did increment the value of `c`. I updated my original post. Please check.

Comment: @Ashar i see no reason of not simplifying it to `set/ac+=1`

Comment: Depending upon the content of `index.txt`, there may be no reason to use `set` or delay expansion at all! `@(For /F "Tokens=1,* Delims=[]" %%G In ('%__AppDir__%find.exe /N /V "" ^< "index.txt"') Do @(Echo incvalue=%%G& Echo line=%%H))&Pause`